# Error:C2016 C requires that a struct or union has at least one member

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, struct

I am a newbie in c/c++ and faced a problem using some `c` project headers in `c++`.

I have two solutions, where #one containing mostly `c` files (also few `cpp`) and the #two only `cpp` files. each solution gets compiled and runs correctly with no errors.
both are on VisualStudio `v.15.9.4 VC++ 2017` targeting `windows SDK 10.0.17134.0`.

I did copy-paste some header files form #one to #two and on compile get the error in the title.

```
typedef struct
{
    U32 RESERVED;
    SHARED_TYPE *  SHARED;
    struct
    {
    } ALIEN; <--- HERE
} TxRequest;

Error   C2016   C requires that a struct or union has at least one member 
Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration
```

searching answers mostly where about the difference of compilers but
targeting the same SDK where not both solutions using the same compiler? why in one solution it get compiled with no error and in one with error?

how should I fix it having the same empty struct. as changing it might affect other parts.

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty struct?

Comment: C++ supports empty structs, but I really wonder what could be a use case.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Throwing an exception of that type is one use case.

Comment: @NathanOliver don't know yet, it is part of protocol stack with hundreds of files

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  They share a common subset, but each also has incompatibilities with the other.  It is by no means safe to suppose that you can pick up arbitrary C++ code and compile it as C, or vice versa.  That the compiler used is in some sense the same has little to do with it.

Comment: If I had to guess this is being compiled as a C file not C++, but I don't see the use for an empty struct optimization will probably remove it. @JohnBollinger bring the point home

Comment: Perhaps an `#ifdef __CPLUSPLUS` could isolate the empty `struct`

Comment: @Jabberwocky "C++ supports empty structs" then what is the source of the error?

Comment: @OliverCiappara I really do not know, how and where I can undrestand what compiler VS is using for compiling each file? the two solutions that are opned in the identical environemt are treated differently regarding compilation?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi .c files are compiled as C and .cpp files are compiled as C++. C++ supports empty structs but C does not.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks, but that is not the point, the same file in another solution get compiled without any error. even the same solution in AzureDevopls get build successfully. but the copy pasted version in the new solution faces this problem

Answer (score 4):

Standard C does not permit empty structs, as the error message helpfully points out. Standard C++ does allow them, since they can be useful as template metavalues and for overload resolution, among other purposes.

From the error message, it seems that you are compiling that header with the Visual Studio C compiler.

Other compilers are more lenient. Empty C structs are a long-standing GCC extension, and were frequently used, as in this example, as another form of the so-called ["struct hack"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043). In its classic form, the struct hack consisted of putting an array of length 1 (or, using gcc, length 0) as a kind of placeholder for a variable length extension. In this case, the variable length extension is presumably a single object of unspecified type, as opposed to the classic struct hack where it is an array of objects of specified type but unspecified length.

So GCC (and Clang) accept that `struct` declaration as valid C unless you request strict validation with `-pedantic` (and even then, it shows up as a warning, not an error).

In general, a `union` would be a better solution here. But that requires knowing the various possible extensions to `TxRequest`, so it might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I still did not get, How and why Visual Studio compile them with two different compilers? is there a way to force VS to compile both solutions with the same compiler?

Comment: @amir: I believe one is being compiled as C and the other one as C++. That doesn't depend on the header. What matters is the language used in the file which includes the header.